# Datatables won't work inside Sys.Application.add_load

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, datatables, updatepanel

I have this gridview which needs fixed header and column. So I'm using datatables to do the job for me.

That's the code I'm using:

```
<script>
        function initDataTable(){
            $("#grdPrincipal").DataTable({
            scrollY: 210,
            scrollX: true,
            fixedHeader: true,
            fixedColumns: true,
            paging: false,
            //ordering: false,
            info: false,
            searching: false,
            select: true
        });
        }

        //initDataTable();
        Sys.Application.add_load(initDataTable);
        
</script>
```

It won't work if I run `Sys.Application.add_load(initDataTable);` or if I run `$(document).ready(initDataTable);`. It says that the element doesn't support property or method DataTable.
[image: Error]

**But if I simply run `initDataTable();`  outside any of both functions, it works.**

My datatable is perfectly generated, it has the following structure:

[image]

I'm trying to use it with `add_load` because the datatable is inside a UpdatePanel.

---

I have searched a lot and I couldn't find any working solution.

I'm using both `GridView1.UseAccessibleHeader = true;` and `GridView1.HeaderRow.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableHeader;` in my gridview's `PreRender` event.

---

**Update:**

After removing jQuery from the master page it seems to work a little bit, but that's weird, right? I'm using a jQuery selector to pick my table.

Answer (score 0):

Ok boys, the show is over.

The problem was that my master page was calling jQuery twice. It was calling jQuery on the top of the page and on the bottom, again.